# Bind a Date in milliseconds representation

Tags: date, playframework, pojo, milliseconds

I need to bind a Date using the milliseconds representation in a controller (i.e. milliseconds from 01.01.1970). I tried using `@As("S")` but had no success, it fails as soon the value is at least 1000. Is there really no way to do this without writing a custom binder?

Edit: Seems like writing a custom binder is the way to go because Play's `DateBinder` uses `SimpleDateFormat` and because of [this bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4148168). `SimpleDateFormat` doesn't accept these kinds of formats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK there's no way, because the binder is just trying to parse expecting the date fields (and the Date millisec field are just 3 digit), and it will not calculate anything.

It's better to bind millisecs to Long and then create Date with it.